# Get data from XML with PHP (but very specific constraint)

Tags: php, xml

Here is my issue :

I have a XML file with this patern :

```
<doc_xml>
  <ad>
     <ref>123456</ref>
     <date>20150101</date>
     <title>My first child title</title>
  </ad>
  <ad>
     <ref>897510</ref>
     <date>20170211</date>
     <title>My second child title</title>
  </ad>
</doc_xml>
```

That I want to do is to get all the data of one of child of < ad > but only if < ref > value is (for exemple) = 123456, so in this case, get only this list of data with my request :

```
$ref = 123456;
$date = 123456;
$title = 'My first child title';
```

Currently, I have this code in PHP :

```
xml=simplexml_load_file("file.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$ref = '123456';
$data = $xml->xpath("/doc_xml/ad/ref[contains(., '$ref')]
");
print_r($data);
```

That allow me to get this array :

```
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 123456 ) )
```

But I can't find how to get the value of the other child (on the same level, `<date>` and `<title>`).

Hope I am clear enough. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Conditions in Xpath can be at any position an a lot more complex.

`contains()` looks wrong - for example `123456` contains `234`. I suggest using `normalize-space()` and equals.

You have two possible solutions:

## Fetch the `ad` element with the specific `ref`

return the `ad` elements:
 
`/doc_xml/ad`

... with a `ref` child element:
 
`/doc_xml/ad[ref]`

... that equals a specific text:
 
`/doc_xml/ad[normalize-space(ref) = '123456']`

## Use Xpath with the ref node as context

return all `ad` elements:
 
`/doc_xml/ad/ref[normalize-space(.) = '123456']`

With the found `ref` elements as context, fetch a sibling `title`

`../title`

or:

`parent::*/title`

Using a node in SimpleXML as context means that you call the method `xpath()` on that node. In DOM you provide it as the second argument for `DOMXpath::evaluate()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = $xml->xpath("/doc_xml/ad/ref[contains(., '$ref')]/parent::*");
print_r($data);
```

Find the child and move `xpath` to `parent` of that child.  So you will get the array of data as follows

```
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [ref] => 123456 [date] => 20150101 [title] => My first child title ) )
```

Comment: let's simplify and go the the `<ad>` node directly: `$data = $xml->xpath("/doc_xml/ad[ref='123456']")[0];` and then do `echo $data->title;` and `echo $data->date;`, see it working: https://eval.in/460761